# Get-QADUser Mailbox?

Tags: powershell, quest, powershell-5.1

I have a really generic/basic question. (Please close if not allowed)

Currently, I've been adding the `quest.activeroles.admanagement` snapin to run the QAD cmdlets. Is anyone familiar with how to find Organizational Mailboxes a user is attached to? Their regular user accounts other users are added/given permissions to, in order for them to send emails from and stuff of that nature.

The following is what I've been using to get what distros a user is a part of based on the container in AD:

```
Get-QADGroup -SearchRoot 'Distribution Lists' -ContainsMember abraham.alaniz
```

Unfortunately, since the objects are regular user accounts there's no option/parameter to search what other mailboxes they may be attached to.

The following returns the users/mailboxes that are part of the container for "Org Boxes".

```
Get-QADUser -SearchRoot 'Organizational Accounts'
```

There's no attribute in AD that gives me that information (or at least that I am aware of). Does anyone know how this can be accomplished (in regards to finding other user accounts/mailboxes a user is a part of)? Pardon if this comes off as confusing.

What we have is just a list of all the organization mailboxes/accounts, that are queried for each user in that account

Comment: why are you using the Quest AD stuff? it has apparently been discontinued ... and the built in AD and Exchange and o365 cmdlets are supposed to cover things quite well.

Comment: Only for the user friendliness aspect of it, no real reason.

Comment: if you are going to stick with that outdated [download links removed in 2014], unsupported software, then you likely otta add a tag for `quest` to your Question.

Comment: ahh, i could've sworn i did!

Comment: good luck! i am back to lurking ... [*grin*]

Comment: the infamous "[grin]" lol thanks!!

Comment: that spelled out emoticon stuff does seem to be recognized. i've received the "extended discussions" nag ... so this thread is over for me. [*grin*]